# How do I scale translate x,y values?

Tags: p5.js

I am working on a 2d grid with scale touch functionality. I've managed to set the translate boundaries so that the screen viewport doesn't go beyond the grid boundaries. I'm now struggling with the algorithm for determining the new translate values when scaling on both two finger touch and mouse wheel events.

***touchStarted*** sets the vector angle between the two initial touches. ***lastTouchAngle*** is for comparison in touchMoved.

```
function touchStarted() {
  if(touches.length == 2) {
    let touchA = createVector(touches[0].x, touches[0].y);
    let touchB = createVector(touches[1].x, touches[1].y);
    lastTouchAngle = touchA.angleBetween(touchB);
  }
  return false;
}
```

***touchMoved*** makes the current touches vectors, compares the angle, and then scales accordingly.

***t_MinX*** and ***t_MinY*** set the lowest possible translate value for the constrains, but determining what the new translate value should be is where I'm lost. I know it's going to require the current scale, the center point between the two touches, and the width and height of the Canvas.

```
function touchMoved() {
  if(touches.length == 1) {
    panTranslate(translateX, translateY, mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  } else if (touches.length == 2) {
    let touchA = createVector(touches[0].x, touches[0].y);
    let touchB = createVector(touches[1].x, touches[1].y);

    scl = (abs(lastTouchAngle) < abs(touchA.angleBetween(touchB)) ? (scl+sclStep < sclMax ? scl+sclStep : sclMax) : (scl-sclStep > sclMin ? scl-sclStep : sclMin));
    
    let t_MinX = (screenH/sclMin) * (sclMin-scl);
    let t_MinY = (screenW/sclMin) * (sclMin-scl);
    let tX = translateX;
    let tY = translateY;
    
    if(abs(lastTouchAngle) > abs(touchA.angleBetween(touchB))) {
      console.log("Scale out");
      translateX = constrain(tX+mX, t_MinX, 0);
      translateY = constrain(tY+mY, t_MinY, 0);
      
    } else {
      console.log("Scale in");
      if(scl != sclMax) {
        translateX = constrain(tX-mX, t_MinX, 0);
        translateY = constrain(tY-mY, t_MinY, 0);
      }
    }
    // Set current touch angle to lastTouchAngle
    lastTouchAngle = touchA.angleBetween(touchB);
    
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is the bit getting me confused:

```
      translateX = constrain(tX+mX, t_MinX, 0);
      translateY = constrain(tY+mY, t_MinY, 0);
```

Full code: https://editor.p5js.org/OMTI/sketches/9ux6Rq6n5

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713174

I found the answer at the above link and was able to get this working from the answer there.